# How do I get user's checked-in places' categories?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I want to get logged in user's Check-ins along with the category of the place he has checked-in.

I tried to fetch the user likes and their categories and this is what worked for me - "/me/likes?fields=category" 
Following is the response returned:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "11 East Street Cafe",
        "category": "Restaurant/Cafe",
        "id": "94871278677"
    },{
        "name": "ABC DEF",
        "category": "Politician",
        "id": "177526890164"
    }],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "NDkyMzg4OTc3NTYyMjk3",
            "after": "MTc3NTI2ODkwMTY0"
        }
    }
}
```

For check-ins, I tried "/me/feed?with=location&fields=place,story" and it returns the checked in places list. It returns me following:

```
    {
    "data": [{
        "place": {
            "id": "117586118328311",
            "name": "Carraba's",
            "location": {
                "city": "Ellicott City",
                "country": "United States",
                "latitude": 39.27153726574,
                "longitude": -76.800542073324,
                "state": "MD",
                "zip": "21043"
            }
        },
        "story": "ABC was at Carraba's.",
        "id": "1533836476934935_1546360939015822"
    }, {
        "place": {
            "id": "876737405718973",
            "name": "Chipotle Mexican Grill",
            "location": {
                "city": "Baltimore",
                "country": "United States",
                "latitude": 39.2866707,
                "longitude": -76.6196671,
                "state": "MD",
                "street": "300 W Pratt St",
                "zip": "21201"
            }
        },
        "story": "Aadya Extentia was at Chipotle Mexican Grill.",
        "id": "1533836476934935_1546360502349199"
    }],
    "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/1533836476934935/feed?fields=place,story&wi…WzlgXDpe8ZCV8kHWcO2aNxlARSpwIZByS9OWkU8VC3nj2E3VoiLkJNpy2ESOI1R7fHIOJQZDZD"
    }
}
```

But it does not return the category of checked-in place. i.e. I want know if it is a restaurant, museum or stadium, etc.

How do I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: did you got account (FB developer )yet ???

Comment: Of course, yes. Thats why I got the desired response while fetching user likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though a *Place* is a *Page*, I can't successfully retrieve the `category` field through *Field Expansion*...

This can be done with a batch request, by using the output of the first query as input for the second query:

```
curl \
    -F 'access_token={USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}' \
    -F 'include_headers=false' \
    -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-places","relative_url":"me/feed?with=location&fields=place{id,name,location},story&limit=100", "omit_response_on_success": false },{"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=get-places:$.data.*.place.id}&fields=id,name,category"}]' \
    https://graph.facebook.com
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion):

```
/me/feed?with=location&fields=place{name,category},story
```

---

Edit: Looks like this is working for API version <= 2.4 only, but not any more with v2.5.

Edit #2: I filed a bug report to ask if this was deliberately removed, or if it is a bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1550467468600884/

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, too. Getting a `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (category) on node type (Place)` though.

Comment: @Tobi: In my test in GAE it worked …? Could it depend on the place itself perhaps? I just created a test post with a location, the first location it suggested to me was LA International Airport, so I used that – and I got a `place` structure in the result with name, id and category “Airport”.

Comment: Are you using v2.5? @CBroe https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/

Comment: @Tobi yes, 2.5. // Docs don’t show a `category` field for `place`, yes – but `page` objects have a category, and `place` should refer to a page. Do you have a post with a location in your feed that you can test this on, `/post-id?fields=place{name,category}`? If that gives an error, can you check the place object – is there anything unusual about it? Even for posts that don’t have a place set, I can make that request and don’t get any error.

Comment: @CBroe: Even I am getting the same error "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (category) on node type (Place)"

Comment: Is it because, some of the places I am fetching might not belong to any category?

Comment: Places are pages, and pages _have_ to be in a category AFAIK. Anyway, in that case the field should just come back blank.

Comment: Damn, now I’m getting that error too? It worked before, _I swear_ …

Comment: Damn, @Tobi was right, it does depend on the API version. I was _not_ using 2.5, I had switched to 2.3 in Graph API Explorer (as a quick measure to see all fields available), and there it works. In 2.4 it does as well, but in 2.5 – no more.

Comment: I tend to think that it's a bug... Thanks for raising this with FB.

Comment: Looking at latest update from the issue raised by Christoph,its clear that user has to send a batch request in order to fetch the checked-in place's category. Thanks Christoph!!